# Earth's rotation speed vs latitude

Tags: earth, rotation

The above question may sound naive. Still I would be thankful to someone who helps me in understanding  the concept.

In the following link it is mentioned that earth's rotation speed with respect to  latitude varies as cosine of the latitude.

http://image.gsfc.nasa.gov/poetry/ask/a10840.html

My question is how the rotation speed varies with cosine of latitude?